# oracle find specific character in a string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

What I wanted is to test if a string has a dot. Something like this:

```
IF (a condition that will test if the string 'first.name' has dot) THEN
    some statements;
ELSE 
    some statements;
END IF;
```

Comment: The marked question are not same as what has been asked. Its doesnot appear duplicate to me. Can be reopened.

Comment: You can use the command `REGEXP_LIKE(your_string, '[*.*]' )` in the `IF` condition to check if the string contains a `.` or not.

Comment: @XING you're the one who solved my problem. Thanks bro!

Comment: I think this a flaw with SO. Anyone with enough reputation can close a question without proper answer by just marking it duplicate. I think there should be provision to recheck its validity by others as well. I wanted to post a full answer to your question but couldnot post any comments as the question is marked duplicate.

Comment: I agree with you